# Automate for loop to increase samples selected

Tags: r, for-loop, sample, iris-dataset

I am looking to run a loop that selects 2 rows from a data frame 1000 times > store that into an object >  then run the same loop that selects 3 rows 1000 times > store to object > then 4, and so on. The end goal is to compare the means/variances of the columns when different numbers of rows are randomly selected in the loop.

**Code**

```
iris<- iris

results2<- list()


counter<- 0
for (i in 1:1000) {
  # sample 2 randomly selected rows 1000 times
  tempsample2<- iris[sample(1:nrow(iris), 2, replace=F), ]
  
  # store results of sampling into the created list
  results2[[i]]= tempsample2

  
  counter<- counter+1
  print(counter)
}
```

I can manually store all of these loops into separate objects to then make comparisons, but I'm guessing that there is an easier way to do that. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Package built around this purpose: https://rsample.tidymodels.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` and save the output as nested list.

```
select_rows <- 2:4
n_times <- 5
inds <- nrow(iris)

result <- lapply(select_rows, function(x) 
                replicate(n_times, iris[sample(inds, x), ], simplify = FALSE))
```

Change `select_rows` and `n_times` as per your choice.

Comment: This does work, thanks! My next step was to use bind_rows() to convert the nested list to a dataframe to then make the comparisons, but using that I can't distinguish which rows were pulled in which sample....would I add a statement to the lapply to somehow give an ID to each sample?

Comment: `bind_rows` has `.id` argument which can help to give a unique Id for each dataframe.

Comment: I don't want to think about how long it would've taken me to realize that simple answer- thanks so much